# Intercepting Changes in Breezejs and turning them into new records

Tags: breeze, asp.net-web-api

I have a javascript application that saves changes in the front end, pushes them to a WebAPI controller and saves them to an Entity Framework context.  In order to save a history of the changes made to the table I would like to intercept certain edits to certain tables and change them from an edit row type command to a new row command with the edited data.  My current controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
{
    return _ContextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}
```

How can I set this up to create the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the 'saveMap' that is part of the BeforeSaveEntities delegate or overridden method.  Use the ContextProvider's CreateEntityInfo method to create items to add to the saveMap.

```
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
    _ContextProvider.BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate = CreateNewFoo;
    return _ContextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}

// the saveMap parameter contains the entities that were passed from the client to be saved
// you can add to the map here:
private Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> CreateNewFoo(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap) {
  // create your new entity.
  var foo = new Foo();
  foo.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
  // SaveOptions.Tag is free form data that can be passed from the client.
  var tag = ContextProvider.SaveOptions.Tag;
  foo.Comment = (tag == null) ? "Generic comment" : tag.ToString();

  // create an EntityInfo object from the new entity
  var ei = ContextProvider.CreateEntityInfo(foo);

  // add it to the saveMap
  List<EntityInfo> fooInfos;
  if (!saveMap.TryGetValue(typeof(Foo), out fooInfos)) {
    fooInfos = new List<EntityInfo>();
    saveMap.Add(typeof(Foo), fooInfos);
  }
  fooInfos.Add(ei);

  // return the updated saveMap
  return saveMap;
}
```

Comment: p.s. ContextProvider should read _ContextProvider to access the local variable and not the static class.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the Entity out of the saveMap in a strongly typed way so I can pull info out of it to place in my Foo?

Comment: The EntityInfo has an Entity property. Why not simply cast the result of your EntityInfo.Entity property to the correct type? So in the method above you code add IEnumerable<Foo> foos = fooInfos.Select(fi => (Foo) fi.Entity); or am I missing something?

Comment: That is what I ended up doing/figuring out.  Slowly wrapping my head around this.